# Graphic Scale for Rating the Truth level

Tags: icons, input-fields, graphs, ratings, scale

Imagine you have a text of characteristic/description about you. But this text is **truthful to some extent** (from 0 to 100%).

What is the best UI/UX way for a **mobile user** to **rate** this truthfulness?

The scale doesn't have to be very precise (like *0%, 1%, 2%... 99%, 100%*). 3 or 4 truth-levels would be enough. It can be a verbal+graphic (*not true*... *fantastically true*) or rating using some emoji-like symbols.

Any ideas are welcome, please help! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Don't get into specifics here. The idea is

### Show amount/level/percentage

The labels or milestones may be specific like **30% or 4/10 or Right** or non-precise like **Not much, Almost there or Pretty much the truth**

The visual representation would, however, be somewhat like in the so :-

[image: Visual representation of completion percentage]
[image: Mobile UI example]
[image: Mobile UI precise example]

Try [Pintrest](https://in.pinterest.com) for more examples like **[these](https://in.pinterest.com/explore/progress-bar/?lp=true)**

Comment: I am so confused by that last example.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend adapting a [Likert-like scale](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likert_scale), replacing if you must the idea of agree/disagree with true/untrue.  This is a well-proven format most users will recognize intuitively.  It also allows for compact/inline controls if you're goal is to increase density without loss of clarity; chunkier representations may be pretty, but they aren't strictly necessary.

More than anything, though, it removes the arbitrary and cumbersome attachment to numerical representation.  If "somewhat true" maps to 75% under the hood, that's up to you, but users are frequently more hurt than helped by numbers for non-quantifiable terms, so getting them out of sight should improve both consistency and willingness of participation.